# ComboBoxItem content not displaying before mouseover?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

The content in my comboboxitem selection is not displaying in the combobox when the control is loaded. It appears after I mouseover and works thereafter.

Here's the combobox item that is selected by default

```
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="ModeSet">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="=" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Set" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ComboBoxItem>
```

when I load the window with this control, the combobox is just blank. Then when I mouseover, the content appears in it.

```
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="ModeSet" Content="Test"/>
```

This works, and the content displays correctly from the start, so im guessing theres something wrong with my grid or its contents?

edit: heres the combobox definition from the xaml:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding ModeSelection, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Margin="5"
                  SelectedValuePath="Name">
```

Its defaulting to the `"ModeSet"` ComboBoxItem correctly, the issue seems to be purely visual with the  content not displaying correctly.

Comment: Hi Olli, can you share some info of how you're loading the data?

Comment: What do you mean? The ComboBoxItem snippet I have above is inside a ComboBox control which is on a custom control that is added to my window through a command.

Comment: Did you set SelectedIndex of ComboBox?

Comment: I've added the ComboBox definition to the original post above. SelectedValue is bound to the ModeSelection property, which is initialized as `"ModeSet"`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with XAML in Xamarin.Forms you could try:

```
<ComboBoxItem x:Name="ModeSet">
      <ComboBoxItem.Content>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Text="=" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
          <TextBlock Text="Set" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
      </ComboBoxItem.Content>
    </ComboBoxItem>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't seem to have made any difference unfortunately.